# Validation error gone when lost focus Angular form

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a angular reactive form

The html file

```
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input formControlName="addressNumber" matInput type="number" [placeholder]="addressNumber"/>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="warnColorText">{{errorMessage}}</div>
```

The ts file

```
           this.editForm = this.fb.group({
            addressNumber: [0, [
            Validators.required,
            this.formValidation.customMinMaxValidation(2, 256)
        ]],
         ...});
```

I also have code to add async validator in the ts file after the form is initialized.

```
this.editForm.get('addressNumber').setAsyncValidators([this.formValidation.uniqueNumberValidation()]);
```

Everything works fine. If the number is not unique, the form will display an error. However, the error is gone if the field is lost focus. What could cause the error disappearing when the field is out of focus?

Comment: how are you populating the `errorMessage` variable?

Comment: errorMessage is returned from validation function,

Answer (score 2):

Are you using angular material? I assume so, from the html you provided.

Did you try adding the error message inside the `<mat-form-field>` tags?
like in their documentation @ https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages

e.g.

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input formControlName="addressNumber" matInput type="number [placeholder]="addressNumber"/>
    <mat-error *ngIf="addressNumber.invalid">{{errorMessage}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can bind the `errorMessage` for your custom validation and use directly in your HTML through @rxweb/reactive-form-validators, you need to declare your custom validation in custom validators like this :

```
 addressNumber:['',RxwebValidators.compose({validators:[this.uniqueNumberValidation()]})]
```

As per this example if you add `1` in addressNumber the errorMessage will be displayed.

Component ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,AbstractControl } from "@angular/forms"
import { RxFormBuilder,RxwebValidators } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-compose-validators',
    templateUrl: './compose-validators.component.html'
})
export class ComposeValidatorsComponent implements OnInit {
    userFormGroup: FormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
          addressNumber:['',RxwebValidators.compose({validators:[this.uniqueNumberValidation()]})]
        });
    }
     uniqueNumberValidation() {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        if (control.value != 1)
            return null;
        else
            return {
                'addressNumber': { message: "Address Number Should be Unique" }
            };
    }
}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Address Number</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="addressNumber" class="form-control" />
      <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="userFormGroup.controls.addressNumber.errors">{{userFormGroup.controls.addressNumber.errorMessage}}<br /></small>
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="!userFormGroup.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utbzbn)

Comment: Thanks for posting these codes although I already have similar codes in my projects. I think I found the problem. If I remove type="number" in my original code, every thing works fine. Again, my problem is that the invalid uniqueness error will gone when the field is out of focus.

Comment: @user3097695 Please share stackblitz or show the validation function where you have bind the errorMessage

Comment: I subscribe the valueChange of the control and and assign something to the errorMessage when there is an error. I will try to write some thing up next week. However, I never used stackblitz before.